# Problemas con array en PHP

Tags: php

Amigos tengo un array que viene de una base de datos con el siguiente formato:

```
["2018-07-25","2018-07-26","2018-07-26"]
```

Con un json decode lo convierto en un array, con el fin de poder tratarlo ya que el código es para buscar una fecha y quitarla del array y luego devolverlo a la base de datos.

Para hacer eso uso el siguiente código:

`$ls['fecha']`

es el texto con el array que viene de la base de datos.

`$_POST['glo']`

es la fecha a buscar.

```
    $arra = json_decode($ls['fecha']);

    if (in_array($_POST['glo'], $arra, true)) {

        $este = array_keys($arra, $_POST['glo']);
        $clave = array_search($_POST['glo'], $arra);
        unset($arra[intval($clave)]);

        $sql = "UPDATE tabla SET fecha = '".json_encode($arra, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."' WHERE r = '".$_POST['r']."'";
        $con = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);

    }
```

En efecto el busca y elimina la fecha pero al guardar el array nuevamente en la db cambia el formato del array, asi:

```
{"0":"2018-07-25","2":"2018-07-26"}
```

Y necesitoq ue el array quede asi:

```
["2018-07-25","2018-07-26"]
```

Alguna Solución ?? o algo estoy haciendo mal??  Mil gracias

Comment: lo que sucede es que cuando guardas en formato json, el viene tiene internamente su formato Key - Value, por eso te guarda asi, deberias de guardarlo como posiciones de array mejor

Comment: Y como podría hacerlo?

Comment: el array siempre guarda dos fechas ?

Comment: No queda muy claro cómo se almacenan las fechas en bbdd. Dices `necesito que el array quede así ["2018-07-25","2018-07-26"]`, pero eso no es un json. Para qué utilizar json_encode entonces? Podrías aclarar este punto, por favor?

Comment: bueno, puedes motrarme el codigo donde traes el dato de la bd ?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablaWHERE r = '".$_POST['r']."'";
 $con = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
 $ls = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con);
 
 if (is_null($ls['fecha'])) {
  $glo = array();
  array_push($glo, $_POST['glo']);
 }else{
  $glo = json_decode($ls['fecha']);
  array_push($glo, $_POST['glo']);
 }
 
 $sql2 = "UPDATE tablaSET fecha ='".json_encode($glo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."' WHERE r = '".$_POST['r']."'";
 $con2 = mysqli_query($conx, $sql2);

Comment: Con ese codigo es que se ingresan las fechas y pueden ser cuantas el cliente necesite

Comment: agrega el sql del update a la pregunta (hay un link editar justo debajo de las etiquetas)

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, recibes una cadena como esta de la base de datos:

`["2018-07-25","2018-07-26","2018-07-26"]`  y quieres convertirlo en array para quitar un valor determinado y luego devolver ese array a la base de datos.

Propondré un código para hacer lo que quieres, aunque me pregunto por qué traes datos para desecharlos en vez de aplicar un filtro al seleccionar los datos... pero ese es otro asunto.

La solución que propongo consiste en lo siguiente:

- **a.** Convertir la cadena dada en un array mediante el uso de `json_decode`
- **b.** Al mismo tiempo aplicar al resultado del array obtenido en **a** la función `array_unique` para quitar los posibles valores duplicados.
- **c.** Usar de forma segura `array_search` para buscar un valor dado y removerlo del array mediante `unset`.

El resultado será el mismo array, pero sin el valor que se ha indicado para ser removido.

El código sería este:

```
/*$str representa tus datos reales, a los que no tengo acceso*/
$str='["2018-07-25","2018-07-26","2018-07-26"]';
$arrDatos = array_unique(json_decode($str));
/*Dato que se quiere quitar del array*/
$aBorrar="2018-07-26";
if (($key = array_search($aBorrar, $arrDatos)) !== false) {
    unset($arrDatos[$key]);
}

print_r($arrDatos);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-07-25
)
```

---

#### Prueba de concepto

Puedes ver aquí una <kbd>[**DEMOSTRACIÓN**](http://rextester.com/UUR50225)</kbd> hecha en rextester.

Espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: Agradecería al menos un comentario sobre el por qué del voto negativo... desde hace días parece que ha vuelto algún *troll*  por el sitio. Ya ha votado contra varias respuestas sin explicar el motivo. Actitudes como estas no tienen otro objetivo que afear este sitio que está para ayudarnos unos a otros.

Comment: Yo te doy un +1 por que tus respuestas siempre me ayudan a aprender más aunque no sean mis publicaciones

Answer (score -1):

no entiendo porque necesitas grabar con ese formato tus fechas pero al convertirlo en array siempre te mostrará {"0":"2018-07-25","2":"2018-07-26"}, lo que debes hacer es pasar tu array al formato que tu deseas, espero que el siguiente código te sirva en algo.

```html
$arra = json_decode('["2018-07-25","2018-07-26","2018-07-26"]');

    if (in_array("2018-07-26", $arra, true)) {

        $este = array_keys($arra, "2018-07-26");
        $clave = array_search("2018-07-26", $arra);
        unset($arra[intval($clave)]);

        $valor = "[";
        $i = 1;
        $count = count($arra);
       
        // recorro el nuevo arreglo para pasarlo al formato deseado
        foreach ($arra as $key => $value) {
         if ( $i === $count ) {
          $valor .= '"'.$value.'"';
         }else{
          $valor .= '"'.$value.'",';
         }

         $i++;
        }

        $valor .= "]";
     echo "<pre>"; var_dump($valor); exit();

    }
```